# Escaping backslash with awk in OSX

Tags: bash, awk, quoting

I'm trying to match \N in a field of a csv file.

I've tried

```
awk -F "|" '($12=="\N") {print}' ./filename.csv
awk -F "|" '($12==\N) {print}' ./filename.csv
awk -F "|" '($12==\\N) {print}' ./filename.csv
awk -F "|" '($12==\\\\N) {print}' ./filename.csv
```

nothing works so far

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input. For all we know, you're trying this on a  file that doesn't have `\N` in it.

Answer (score 3):

In Bourne-like (like `bash`), Csh-like or rc-like shells, use:

```
awk -F'|' '$12 == "\\N"'
```

In awk strings, backslash is used to introduce C-like escape sequences like `\b` for backspace, `\n` for newline, `\123` for octal sequences... You need `\\` for backslash itself. `\N` itself is not currently a known escape sequence in any `awk` implementation that I know.

Some `awk` implementations will treat `"\N"` as `\` and `N`, some as `N`, some (gawk) like `N` with a warning message issued. POSIX leaves the behaviour unspecified.

Note that it also applies to strings passed like:

```
awk -F'|' -v value='\\N' '$12 == value'
```

Or:

```
awk -F'|' '$12 == value' value='\\N'
```

You may want to use the environment to pass a value as-is without having to worry about escaping special characters for `awk` (and avoids problems with GNU `awk` 4.2 or above, which [treats value starting with `@/` and ending in `/` specially](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants)):

```
VALUE='\N' awk -F'|' '$12 == ENVIRON["VALUE"]'
```

It also applies to regular expression literals expresses as `/.../` like in:

```
awk -F'|' '$12 ~ /\\N/'
```

However, it's further complicated there by the fact that the backslash is overloaded as that escape-sequence introducer (for `\n`, `\b`...) and as a quoting operator for regexps (`\.` or `\$`... to remove their special meaning of regular expression operator). POSIX is currently unclear (and even doesn't match the reality in some cases) on that in a few corner cases (like on `/\\./` or `/\56/` or `/[\135]/`). Again using `ENVIRON` can help, though not always. For instance:

```
R='[\]' awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["R"]'
```

is meant to match on backslash in POSIX but returns an error in all `awk` implementations that I know. Better to always escape the `\` even inside `[...]` if it's to be taken literally, to be on the safe side.

Note that for the `fish` shell, you need another layer of escaping as for `fish` (contrary to most other shells), `\` is special within single quotes. So you need:

```
awk -F'|' '$12 == "\\\\N"'
```

there. Though

```
awk -F'|' '$12 == "\\\N"'
```

will also work.

```
env 'V=\N' awk -F'|' '$12 == ENVIRON["V"}'
```

should also work (in `fish` and other shell families).

Comment: still not working, at least on osx

Comment: @Bob, `printf '%s\n' '|||||||||||\N|' | awk -F'|' '$12 == "\\N" {print "OK"}'` prints OK for me on FreeBSD or with any other awk implementation and I'd expect OS/X awk to be based on FreeBSD's itself based on the version maintained by Brian Kernighan (the `K` in awk). What does it output for you?

Comment: @Bob, or is it possible that you're using the `fish` shell? Or using that code within backticks?